# Checking for multiple values in one cell using index-match

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am using index-match to check in a table for multiple values. Now my problem is that I have multiple values in one cell.

My sheet looks like this:

[image]

The first formula looks like this:

```
=INDEX(C2:C11;MATCH(F2&G2;INDEX($A$2:$A$11&$B$2:$B$11;0);-1))
```

As you can see, it only works for `HIGH`, but when it comes to `LOW` it is wrong.(is marked in red in the above image)

Any suggestions, how to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to have to pull some type of wildcard match to find a string-in-a-string rather than the appromate [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) lookup using a **-1** as the optional [match_type]¹.

[image: Two column lookup on substring in string]

The array formula² in H2 is,

```
=INDEX($C$2:$C$11; MATCH("*"&G2&"*"; IF($A$2:$A$11=F2; $B$2:$B$11); 0))
```

That formula presupposes that you are not going to get false positives on your sector data by having a sector like **KL** or **TT** that would be found within **PKLP** or **TTL**. If your sectors could produce false positives like that then you will to add the *<comma><space>* delimiter. In this case the array formula² would be,

```
=INDEX($C$2:$C$11; MATCH("*, "&G2&", *"; IF($A$2:$A$11=F2; ", "&$B$2:$B$11&", "); 0))
```

[image: Two column lookup with wildcards]

Note that the *<comma><space>* delimiters have been added to both the source and the target.

¹ <sub>A [match_type] of **1** or **-1** in a [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) should **never** be used on unsorted data. Correct results are more coincidence than reliable when used on unsorted data.</sub>

²<sub>Array formulas need to be finalized with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd>. Once entered into the first cell correctly, they can be filled or copied down or right just like any other formula.</sub>

Comment: Thx for your answer! I am using a european excel version. In the second formula it is unclear to me, what should be substituted by `;`. Would you be so kind to edit your answer! Thx in advance!

Comment: I just realized how confusing that must have looked. Sorry! Changed both formulas above.